# inner or outer exception class in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I have a particular exception that can occur only inside the class `Foo`

Would it be good to use a inner exception class as below:

```
class Foo:
    class FooError(Exception):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        raise self.FooError('omg')
```

Or it is better to put `FooError` outside from `Foo`?

```
class FooError(Exception):
    pass

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        raise FooError('omg')
```

Comment: If you put exception outside, you can you use the same at many places in your code by coding it dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it outside, because of export rules. This exception is only *raised* inside the class, but it might (and probably will) bubble to other parts of the code, so other modules may want to catch it.

If the exception is **outside** the class, you can choose to export only the exception. If the exception is **inside** the class, you have to either export the entire class with the exception, or use something like `__all__ = [Foo.FooError, ...]`, basically mimicking an outside exception.

If the exception was only ever raised *and caught* inside the class, it might make sense, but I still don't consider it idiomatic.